Logged calls not showing for specific (new) user in Activities
We have a new SF user who is C-level and as such is assigned a role higher than a couple of other users on the record. The Record (Person Account) has several logged calls in their activity history. If I log in as the 2 users who already existed, I can see them fine. If I log in as the new user, I cannot see them. Conversely, I created a test logged call with the new user and it is not visible to the other users when logged in as them. I checked and all of the record types are the same. I also verified that the users all have the exact same permission set assignments and are using the same profiles.
We are using Financial Services Cloud if that matters, but I can't seem to see where the breakdown is as to why these logged calls are not visible (other tasks can be seen between all of the users fine, so far it just seems to be that the logged calls don't show).
I also tried going directly to the logged call logged in as the new user and could see everything fine--no error messages and nothing was missing. I also checked the edit page and made sure that there wasn't any filtering set on the Activity section there nor in the Activity Section itself (there isn't).
Any ideas why these might not be visible?

Happy to make improvements to the question if need be (not sure why the downvote).

Do you have "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" enabled in sharing settings? and what does the role hierarchy look like?

@HAlves I believe so. I created a role for this user and there is only one user above who they report to and they have "Edit" permissions to everything. Do you think putting them on their own level one below the CEO can affect this? There are other roles adjacent to this new role, but I assumed anything below even if under a different role would be visible. Thanks.

Have you isolated the issue to be indeed coming from the user's role assignment? Have you tried giving the user a different role to see if the problem goes away?

@Doodool_Tala thanks. I have indeed tried changing the users role to include making it match 100% another user whom has full visibility to the records in the Activity panel. Strangely, I tried adding a test "log a call" entry on the same Account, and it was not visible to the other users, just the user in question. I have checked permissions on the object itself as well, but do not see anything there either that would be preventing...especially strange since the record(s) are visible when visited directly, it is just in the Activities log on the right panel when viewing the Account.
